# SQL/SSIS how to convert from YYYYDDD format to regular DateTime

Tags: sql, date, datetime, ssis

Quick question for you guys. I am currently writing some ETL where I need to parse out a field from a flat file where the date column is in YYYYDDD format. The goal is to load it into a database column and display as YYYY-MM-DD.

How is this best done in the SSIS package? Is there a way to do it in the package? The record body is loaded to a raw table first so if you know custom SQL to take care of this I can just add it to a SQL step to parse it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: The database column should be of data type `DATE` (or in earlier versions of SQL Server, `DATETIME`). These datatypes have no inherent display format. If the column is of data type `VARCHAR` or something like that, **stop right now** and model your database properly.

Comment: It's not sorry it is a date in the DB I was just talking about it displays it for me when you pull it out.

Comment: What are you displaying it in? an application or SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: If it's purely a display issue then it should have nothing to do with the ETL. A date is a date. You load it into a date field then display it afterwards after  the ETL... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
select dateadd(day, cast(right(YYYYDDD, 3) as int) - 1,
               cast(left(YYYYDD, 4) + '0101' as date))
```

SQL Server recognizes strings of the form YYYYMMDD as dates and should always convert them with no error.

Comment: This worked. Will this be fine for leap year, etc. as well?

Comment: @user3494110 . . . It should be.  The `ddd` handles that.  Any idea why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

When I come across YYYYDDD dates, I convert them to real dates using VB in a script transformation:

```
Row.MaturityDate = DateSerial(CInt(Left(Row.MaturityDate,4)),1,CInt(Right(Row.MaturityDate,3))).ToShortDateString
```

In this case, the **MaturityDate** column is a text/string column and set to ReadWrite.  So the dates are read from **MaturityDate** column, modified, then written back to the **MaturityDate** column.

You could add a new column (with a different data type, one of the date data types for example) to the script transformation, read from the incoming column and write to the new outgoing column...keeping the incoming column in tact for reference.

I come across dates in many different formats.  I wrote a VB UDF handling the formats I've come across so far.  If it is useful to you, you are more than welcome to it (NOTE: I'm more familiar with VB6/VBA than VB.Net, so this UDF is more in the VBA style, but still works in VB.Net):

```
    Public Function ParseDate(ByVal pstrDate As String, ByVal pstrFormat As String, Optional ByVal pblnMEDate As Boolean = False) As Date
    Dim pstrYear As String
    Dim pstrMonth As String
    Dim pstrDay As String

    Dim pintYear As Integer
    Dim pintMonth As Integer
    Dim pintDay As Integer

    Dim pint4DigitCurrentYear As Integer
    Dim pint2DigitCurrentYear As Integer

    Dim pdteDate As Date

    Dim pintLen As Integer

    'pint4DigitCurrentYear = Year(mdteMEDate)'
    'pint2DigitCurrentYear = pint4DigitCurrentYear - 2000'


    pstrFormat = UCase(pstrFormat)

    Select Case pstrFormat
        Case "YYYY MMM"
            pstrYear = Left(pstrDate, 4)
            pstrMonth = Right(pstrDate, 3)
            pstrDate = pstrMonth & " " & pstrYear
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)


        Case "MMYYYY"
            pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
            pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
            pstrDate = pstrMonth & " " & pstrYear
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)


        Case "MMMYY"
            pstrDate = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 2) & " 20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
            pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "JLY", "JUL")
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)

        Case "MMM YY"
            pstrDate = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 2) & "20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
            pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "Sept", "Sep")
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)

        Case "MMMYYYY", "MMM YYYY"
            pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
            pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 3)
            pstrDate = pstrMonth & " " & pstrYear
            pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "Sept", "Sep")
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)


        Case "MMMM YY"
            pstrYear = "20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
            pstrMonth = Trim(Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 2))
            pstrDate = pstrMonth & " " & pstrYear
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)

        Case "MMMMYYYY"
            pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
            pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 4)
            pstrDate = pstrMonth & " " & pstrYear
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)


        Case "DATEVALUE"
            pdteDate = DateValue(pstrDate)

        Case Else

            Select Case pstrFormat
                Case "YYYYDDD"
                    pstrYear = Left(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = "1"
                    pstrDay = Right(pstrDate, 3)

                Case "YYYYMMDD"
                    pstrYear = Left(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Mid(pstrDate, 5, 2)
                    pstrDay = Right(pstrDate, 2)

                Case "YYYY-MM-DD"
                    pstrYear = Left(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Mid(pstrDate, 6, 2)
                    pstrDay = Right(pstrDate, 2)

                Case "YYMMDD"
                    pstrYear = "20" & Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Mid(pstrDate, 3, 2)
                    pstrDay = Right(pstrDate, 2)

                Case "YYYY-MM", "YYYYMM", "YYYY MM"
                    pstrYear = Left(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"

                Case "YYMM"
                    pstrYear = "20" & Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"



                Case "DDMMYYYY"
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Mid(pstrDate, 3, 2)
                    pstrDay = Left(pstrDate, 2)



                Case "MDDYYYY", "MMDDYYYY"
                    pintLen = Len(pstrDate)
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, pintLen - 6)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, pintLen - 5, 2)
                Case "MDDYY"
                    pintLen = Len(pstrDate)
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, pintLen - 4)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, pintLen - 3, 2)
                Case "MMDDYY"
                    pstrYear = "20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, 3, 2)

                Case "MM-DD-YYYY", "M-DD-YYYY", "M.DD.YYYY"
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 8)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 6, 2)

                Case "M-DD-YY", "MM-DD-YY", "M/DD/YY", "MM/DD/YY"
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 6)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 4, 2)

                Case "M-DD-YY PAST", "MM-DD-YY PAST", "M/DD/YY PAST", "MM/DD/YY PAST"
                    pintLen = Len(pstrDate)
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)

                    If pintYear > pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "19" & pstrYear
                    ElseIf pintYear <= pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "20" & pstrYear
                    Else
                        pstrYear = "99" & pstrYear
                    End If

                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 6)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 4, 2)

                Case "MMYYDD PAST"
                    'pintLen = Len(pstrDate)'
                    pstrYear = Mid(pstrDate, 3, 2)
                    pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)

                    If pintYear > pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "19" & pstrYear
                    ElseIf pintYear <= pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "20" & pstrYear
                    Else
                        pstrYear = "99" & pstrYear
                    End If

                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = Right(pstrDate, 2)

                Case "DT6 PAST"
                    pintLen = Len(pstrDate)
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)

                    If pintYear > pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "19" & pstrYear
                    ElseIf pintYear <= pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "20" & pstrYear
                    Else
                        pstrYear = "99" & pstrYear
                    End If

                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, pintLen - 4)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, pintLen - 3, 2)
                Case "DT6 PAST PLUS 10"
                    pintLen = Len(pstrDate)
                    'pint4DigitCurrentYear = Year(mdteMEDate) + 10'
                    pint2DigitCurrentYear = pint4DigitCurrentYear - 2000
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)

                    If pintYear > pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "19" & pstrYear
                    ElseIf pintYear <= pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "20" & pstrYear
                    Else
                        pstrYear = "99" & pstrYear
                    End If

                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, pintLen - 4)
                    pstrDay = Mid(pstrDate, pintLen - 3, 2)


                Case "MYY"
                    pstrYear = "20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"
                Case "MMYY", "MM-YY", "MM/YY"
                    pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "-", "")
                    pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "/", "")
                    pstrYear = "20" & Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"
                Case "MMYY PAST", "MM-YY PAST", "MM/YY PAST"
                    pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "-", "")
                    pstrDate = Replace(pstrDate, "/", "")
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 2)
                    pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)
                    If pintYear > pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "19" & pstrYear
                    ElseIf pintYear <= pint2DigitCurrentYear Then
                        pstrYear = "20" & pstrYear
                    Else
                        pstrYear = "99" & pstrYear
                    End If
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"
                Case "MM-YYYY"
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, 2)
                    pstrDay = "1"
                Case "M-YYYY"
                    pstrYear = Right(pstrDate, 4)
                    pstrMonth = Left(pstrDate, Len(pstrDate) - 5)
                    pstrDay = "1"




                Case Else
                    MsgBox("Date Format does not exist in function." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please add it.", vbInformation, "Date Format")
                    'ParseDate = CVErr(xlErrRef)'
                    Exit Function
                    'pstrYear = "9999"'
                    'pstrMonth = "99"'
                    'pstrDay = "99"'
            End Select

            pintYear = CInt(pstrYear)
            pintMonth = CInt(pstrMonth)
            pintDay = CInt(pstrDay)

            pdteDate = DateSerial(pintYear, pintMonth, pintDay)
    End Select

    If pblnMEDate Then
        pdteDate = DateSerial(Year(pdteDate), Month(pdteDate) + 1, 0)
    End If

    'ParseDate = pdteDate.ToShortDateString'
    ParseDate = pdteDate


End Function
```

If anyone has improvements to my code, I'd love to see them.

HTH